# How to make radio button like on/off switches using css

Tags: html, css

I have requirement of radio buttons with on/off method i.e when click on one radio button it should on and when click on second button first button should off but below code is not working as per my expectation.

Here is the snippet for that html and css code:

```css
body {
  background: #0288D1;
}

.checkboxes-and-radios {
  margin: 80px auto 0;
  width: 280px;
  padding: 30px;
  background: #fafafa;
  input {
    display: none;
  }
  label {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-right: 35px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 15px 0
  }
  input[type="checkbox"],
  input[type="radio"] {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden !important;
  }
  input[type="checkbox"]+label,
  input[type="radio"]+label {
    &:before,
    &:after {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      margin-top: -7.5px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    &:before {
      width: 30px;
      height: 15px;
      right: 0px;
      background: #fff;
      border: 1px solid #e4e3e1;
      border-radius: 15px;
    }
    &:after {
      width: 15px;
      height: 15px;
      right: 15px;
      background: #BDBDBD;
      border-radius: 50%;
      transition: all 200ms ease-out;
    }
  }
  input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label,
  input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
    &:after {
      right: 0px;
      background: #FF9800;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="checkboxes-and-radios">
  <h1>Radios:</h1>
  <input type="radio" name="radio-cats" id="radio-1" value="1" checked>
  <label for="radio-1">Radio Label 1</label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio-cats" id="radio-2" value="2">
  <label for="radio-2">Radio Label 2</label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio-cats" id="radio-3" value="3" checked>
  <label for="radio-3">Radio Label 3</label>
  <h1>Checkboxes:</h1>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-cats[]" id="checkbox-1" value="1" checked>
  <label for="checkbox-1">Checkbox Label 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-cats[]" id="checkbox-2" value="2">
  <label for="checkbox-2">Checkbox Label 2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-cats[]" id="checkbox-3" value="3" checked>
  <label for="checkbox-3">Checkbox Label 3</label>
</div>
```

expected output:

[image]

so how to add css that will look like in image shown in top?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp

Comment: how is it any harder to create a snippet than it is to create a fiddle?   Anyway as you won't include your code in the question, it is off topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  As for blatantly ignoring the warning you get when you added the fiddle link and then highlighting a sentence as code...

Comment: @Pete actually code is too long and warning was shown by stackoverflow ,so I decided to add link for jsfiddle

Comment: Then **reduce** the code until it **only shows the relevant issue**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works like a charm for me. In your provided fiddle, the SCSS was not compiled to CSS. Here a compiled version. Radio buttons are switching correctly.

Here also a [version on CodePen](https://codepen.io/Sixl/pen/jQjyKr).

**Your CSS is not CSS but SCSS, which has to be compiled to CSS.**

You have to use a preprocessor to compile scss to css. You should start reading here:
http://sass-lang.com

```css
body {
  background: #0288D1;
}

.checkboxes-and-radios {
  margin: 80px auto 0;
  width: 280px;
  padding: 30px;
  background: #fafafa;
}

.checkboxes-and-radios input {
  display: none;
}

.checkboxes-and-radios label {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding-right: 35px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.checkboxes-and-radios input[type="checkbox"],
.checkboxes-and-radios input[type="radio"] {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden !important;
}

.checkboxes-and-radios input[type="checkbox"]+label:before,
.checkboxes-and-radios input[type="checkbox"]+label:after,
.checkboxes-and-radios input[type="radio"]+label:before,
.checkboxes-and-radios input[type="radio"]+label:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -7.5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.checkboxes-and-radios input[type="checkbox"]+label:before,
.checkboxes-and-radios input[type="radio"]+label:before {
  width: 30px;
  height: 15px;
  right: 0px;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #e4e3e1;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.checkboxes-and-radios input[type="checkbox"]+label:after,
.checkboxes-and-radios input[type="radio"]+label:after {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  background: #BDBDBD;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all 200ms ease-out;
}

.checkboxes-and-radios input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label:after,
.checkboxes-and-radios input[type="radio"]:checked+label:after {
  right: 0px;
  background: #FF9800;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkboxes-and-radios">
  <h1>Radios:</h1>
  <input type="radio" name="radio-cats" id="radio-1" value="1" checked>
  <label for="radio-1">Radio Label 1</label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio-cats" id="radio-2" value="2">
  <label for="radio-2">Radio Label 2</label>
  <input type="radio" name="radio-cats" id="radio-3" value="3" checked>
  <label for="radio-3">Radio Label 3</label>
  <h1>Checkboxes:</h1>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-cats1" id="checkbox-1" value="1" checked>
  <label for="checkbox-1">Checkbox Label 1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-cats2" id="checkbox-2" value="2">
  <label for="checkbox-2">Checkbox Label 2</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-cats3" id="checkbox-3" value="3" checked>
  <label for="checkbox-3">Checkbox Label 3</label>
</div>
```